# How to read a multi nested json file into a database (with Pentaho)

Tags: json, pdi

I have a JSON file with five sub-levels that I need to parse with PDI. I am wondering if I can do this with one JSON input step or do I need to process each level separately. Attached is the screenshot of what I have so far.

[image: enter image here]
Will PDI process all the lower-level data before moving to the next parent level or do I need to parse the top level and then pass that on to another JSON.input step?

Answer (score 0):

i tried working on version 6.2 with 3 levels and had to use multiple json input.for quicker execution

- passed everything as data stream
- in my example, i was working with order headers and order lines so separated them functionally  using one json input for header to populate header details and other for order lines. may be you can use the same approach

if you are using version 8.2 i think this should work for you
https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.3/Products/JSON_Input